# Java Concurrency in Practice: cannot resolve symbol "servlet"

Tags: java, servlets

Code example:

```
public class CountingFactorizer implements Servlet {
    private BigInteger lastNumber;
    private BigInteger[] lastFactors;

    public synchronized void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp) {
        BigInteger i = extractFromRequest(req);
        if (i.equals(lastNumber))
            encodeIntoResponse(resp, lastFactors);
        else {
            BigInteger[] factors = factor(i);
            lastNumber = i;
            lastFactors = factors;
            encodeIntoResponse(resp, factors);
        }

    }
}
```

And it says *cannot resolve symbol "servlet"*.

I downloaded servlet.jar and imported it to the IDE, however, the method *extractFromRequest* and *encodeIntoResponse* still cannot be resolved.

Please tell me how to fix it.

My Java Enrivonment:
Java SE8

Comment: Did you include the import statement?  *import javax.servlet.Servlet*

Comment: Yes, I added the import statement. Should I install tomcat or just import servlet.jar? @EJK

Comment: No need to install Tomcat.  All you need is servlet.jar.  Make sure that it is in the classpath of your project.  You say you "imported it to the IDE", but I am not sure what you mean by that.  Is Eclipse your IDE?

Comment: My IDE is intellij IDEA. I added servlet-api.jar to the project dependency and include the *import javax.servlet.Servlet;*, *import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;*, *
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;*. But some method cannot be resolved and the IDE says *Class 'CountingFactorizer' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'destroy()' in 'Servlet'*

Comment: ok, that sounds like progress.  So you no longer have your originally stated problem "cannot resolve symbol servlet"?

Comment: javax.servet.Servlet is an interface.  If you want to build a class that implements that interface, then you need to implement all of the defined methods in the interface.  That is exactly what the compiler is telling you.

Comment: Thanks! And I'm thinking about that maybe these methods, eg. *extractFromRequest*, are not existed actually.

Comment: However those 2 methods do not exist in the Servlet interface.  So I am not sure where you got them from.

Comment: I got them from the book *Java Concurrency in Practice*. I find out that the author just uses these 2 methods but not give their implementation code. I'm just going to ignore them :)